# Login with OpenID: form is hidden

Tags: bug, openid

On the ServerFault login page, the OpenID and other parts of the form are hidden. Only Google, FB and Email/passwd are shown.

I hacked page's DOM with Chrome Developer Tools, got the fields to display, and **got the login to work**. (There was also a javascript test for user-name, but then that glitched or something on the second try.)

Anyhow, thought you ought to know.  (Also, thanks for the interesting puzzle!)

Comment: Hi, please note openid is currently in removal on stackexchange, please see that post where they talk about linking openid gmail and fb account to the system, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307647/337838 which explain the hidden field IMO

Comment: Hey, wow, I'm a 0.1%-er!  Also, bummer.

Comment: I was a 0.1%-er, too, JimB, so sympathies.